# Showcaseview package highlighting CupertinoTabScaffold (used as BottomNavBar) [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, showcaseview

I am using [showCaseView](https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview) package and when I'm highlighting widgets, cupertinoTabScaffold is also highlighted. ShowCaseWidget wrapping MaterialApp widget so TabScaffold and all other widgets wrapped by ShowCase package. Has anyone encountered this, how to solve this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the color of CupertinoTabScaffold depending on whether "showCaseView" is active now, or not:

```
  tabBar: CustomCupertinoTabBar(
      backgroundColor:
          Provider.of<NotifyShowcaseState>(context).isShowcaseActive //I've created ChangeNotifier class for updating state
              ? const Color(0x99BDBDBD) //dimmed grey if showCase is active
              : null,  //default white color, if showCase is inActive
            ....
        ),
```